# SetEnvIf Request_URI Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to set different rules based on the request uri. In short, I'd like to redirect to a page based on the uri. This is a simple test, I'm exploring setting different rules based on part of the uri. This is what I have so far:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

SetEnvIf Request_URI ^(CLIENT_)([0-9]+)$ CLIENT=$1

RewriteCond %{CLIENT:CLIENT_1}
RewriteRule ^(*)$ test1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{CLIENT:CLIENT_2}
RewriteRule ^(*)$ test2.php [L]
```

I was hoping with this to show:

> test1.php if my url is htttp://www.domain.com/CLIENT_1
>
> test2.php if my url is htttp://www.domain.com/CLIENT_2

but instead I get error 500

> RewriteCond: bad argument line '%{CLIENT:CLIENT_1}'

What am i doing wrong? Thank you.
Note: this is with **Apache 2.4**

**Edit: Modified from comments. This is now what I have.**

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

SetEnvIf Request_URI ^(CLIENT_)([0-9]+)$ CLIENT=$1

RewriteCond %{ENV:CLIENT} ^CLIENT_1$
RewriteRule - test1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:CLIENT} ^CLIENT_2$
RewriteRule - test2.php [L]
```

> The requested URL /CLIENT_1 was not found on this server.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `RewriteCond %{CLIENT} ^CLIENT_1$` instead? Actually I am not even sure if you can evaluate such variables in a RewriteCond, never did that myself, I only use 'em inside php scripts I call. I only mention the syntax suggestion because of how it is defined in the documentation...

Comment: I get RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters now

Comment: `RewriteCond %{ENV:CLIENT} ^CLIENT_1$`

Comment: still getting RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: This has got a dash in there, why? `RewriteRule ^(*)$ - test1.php [L]` It should be `RewriteRule ^(*)$ test1.php [L]` I think. Same for the enxt rule. That might explain what is referred to here with "flag": It assumes "test.php" is meant to be a flag. And actually the pattern makes no sense, does it? Try this instead: `RewriteRule - test1.php [L]`

Comment: Yes you are right, I will edit. Getting RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^(*)$' now

Comment: LOL, just added that to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

So as result of our discussion above this appears to be the final version:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

SetEnvIf Request_URI ^(CLIENT_[0-9]+)$ CLIENT=$1

RewriteCond %{ENV:CLIENT} ^CLIENT_1$
RewriteRule ^ test1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:CLIENT} ^CLIENT_2$
RewriteRule ^ test2.php [L]

RewriteRule ^ test.php [L]
```

Comment: The value of those environment vars was still incorrect, I changed that once more...

Comment: Also It certainly does make sense to have a safe fallback. Added one too.

Comment: So what file is it rewritten to now? And does that file really exist where you expect it to be? You will have to consult your rewrite log for that.

Comment: Argh, sorry, that dash did not make any sense, have a try with that pattern: `^` as shown above now. It should be a catch-all.

Comment: pass through D:/test/CLIENT_1 then custom_errors -> 404.html

Comment: Yeah, just as I just mentioned. Change the patterns again in the RewriteRules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96270/discussion-between-arkascha-and-eric).

Comment: >SetEnvIf Request_URI ^(CLIENT_)([0-9]+)$ CLIENT=$1

That can never match. Request_URI starts with / always.

Comment: @covener Thanks for the hint, though it actually confuses me. I would expect %{Request_URI} to hold the same value as in all other modules. Since this question is dealing with `.htaccess` style files (I also prefer the real configuration, but that is not the point here) I would expect it to hold a relative path here. That is not the case? Why not?